# TypeScript map is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rxjs

I'm getting the error "data.map is not a function". I'm mapping the REST API request which is returning JSON data but the problem seems to be related to the data structure. I think the data returning is data.data and I'm not mapping it properly. Any suggestion will be helpful.

This is the Data structure.
[JSON Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ0u6.png)

Here is my service code.

```
  getAlladvisors$ = this.http.get<IAdvisor[]>("http://localhost:8055/items/advisor")
    .pipe(
      map((data: IAdvisor[]) =>
    data.map(
      a =>
      ({
        name: a.name,
        id: a.id,
        page: a.page,
        multilang: a.multilang
      })
    )
  ),

AdvisorsandQuestions$ = this.http.get<IAdvisorsAndQuestions[]>("http://localhost:8055/items/question")
  .pipe(
    tap(data => console.log("Questions IDs", data))
  );
    
getAdvisorsWithId$ = combineLatest([
      this.getAlladvisors$,
      this.AdvisorsandQuestions$
    ]).pipe(
      map(([product, categories]) =>
        product.map(product => ({
          ...product,
          questionId: categories.find(c => product.id === c.id).questions_Id,
        }) as IAdvisor)
      ),
    );
```

Here is the Interface

```
export interface IAdvisor {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  page: string,
  multilang: boolean  
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading that image right it looks like the array is actually a property on an object. If you do `data.data.map` instead does it work?

Comment: Please `console.log` your data and make sure it's what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about my answer but for the data: <IAdvisor []> it may just be data.

```
  getAlladvisors$ = this.http.get<IAdvisor[]>
       ("http://localhost:8055/items/advisor")
       .pipe(
            map((data: <IAdvisor[]> => {
              if (data) {
                console.log(data);
              }
              return data;
            }),
            catchError((error) => {
                 console.log(error)
           }
         })
```